# How to post one comment for all the translated posts

Tags: comments, translation

I have a commenting system with wordpress multilingual website on custom post type "recipe". Where anyone can comment my issue is i have english, spanish and german as my website language.. if someone add a comment in english language for "recipe 1" it only visible on english recipe.. i need it to appear on all the language regardless of comment language.

Comment: Without knowing how you set up your multilingual site (Polylang? WPML? Something else?) it's impossible to answer this accurately.

Comment: i am using wpml